# Use SOAP API creating account issue

Tags: soap-api, soap

I am doing this trailhead (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_soap) and done everything whatevet mention in this and i got success message that account is created but when i click on the check & challenge button it's showing error message

> Challenge not yet complete... here's what's wrong: It doesn't appear
>   that you have logged in using SoapUI.

i have changed the url login into https://na30.force.com/services/Soap/c/43.0/00D28000000W51I

[image]

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
  xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>

       00D29000000W51I!AQ0AQITKnUtm959kozyLqpu.c8Kki7cVuT.
        E2f7dgKHpalQss_MAM2cUiFtcLR516JTFauDnM2HX6AWHUkKOGj3jttYah.C9
       </urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:create>

             <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Name>Bluebeards Grog House</Name>
               <description>It is better than Blackbeards.</description>
        </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:create>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

---output window---

```
       <soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
         xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <soapenv:Header>
          <LimitInfoHeader>
           <limitInfo>
               <current>5</current>
                <limit>5000</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
             </limitInfo>
       </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <createResponse>
          <result>
            <id>0010I00001ujGYsQAM</id>
            <success>true</success>
         </result>
      </createResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you created the Account into the Right Playground ORG?

Comment: yes i have created

Comment: You have to call the `login` method using SoapUI, as specified in the directions on the trailhead. It's not sufficient to use any other existing Session Id for this purpose.

Comment: after using login method i got sessionid . without login how can i get sessionid. i am wondering account is created with name of Bluebeards Grog House and description It is better than Blackbeards.

Answer (score 1):

Trailhead will be looking for a `LoginHistory` record in the verification org that indicates SoapUI was used to establish a session.

I revisited this challenge to see what was going on. I initially used a really old dev org and ran into the same problem you did. The verification kept complaining that:

> It doesn't appear that you have logged in using SoapUI.

Which was odd, as I'd explicitly performed the login and create calls via Soap UI.

In my case I found the problem was with the org itself. Trailhead didn't like that it had a namespace assigned for packaging.

Instead I switched to Trailhead Playground org and repeated the login and create calls. Here is what the LoginHistory looked like when the verification passed:

```
LoginType: Other Apex API
LoginUrl: login.salesforce.com
TlsProtocol: TLS 1.2
Browser: Unknown
Platform: 
Status: Success
Application: N/A
ClientVersion: N/A
ApiType: SOAP Partner
ApiVersion: 36.0
```

Try a SOQL query like the following to check. You will also see the Trailhead application login this way to perform the verification.

```
Select Id,UserId,LoginTime,LoginType,SourceIp,LoginUrl,LoginGeoId,TlsProtocol,Browser,Platform,Status,Application,ClientVersion,ApiType,ApiVersion from LoginHistory order by LoginTime desc`
```

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the same issue:
After the login response in returned with sessionID, in this response there is a tag for "ServerUrl" just above session id 
"serverUrl"https://xxxxx/services/Soap/c/48.0/xxx"/serverUrl"
            xxxxxx

Use this URL in the create request

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the "It doesn't appear that you have logged in using SoapUI." error, I had to remove the LoginScopeHeader section from the header on the login call .